# Updating user host limit filter in mysql cause Access denied for user while selecting a view

Tags: mysql

When views are created in mysql db, it is created with a definer and adds sql security as a definer by default. For instance, below create view sql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
VIEW 'test_view' AS
    SELECT * FROM  'db'.'account'
```

results into

```
CREATE
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED
    DEFINER = 'someuser'@'%'
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW 'test_view' AS
    SELECT
        'account'.'SystemId' AS 'SystemId'
    FROM
        'account
```

When host restriction is updated on the user account (in this example someuser@%) to more narrower like someuser@10.10.%.%, selecting a view like (select * from test_view) results into access denied error

> Access denied for user 'someuser'@'10.10.%.%' (using password: YES)

The only workaround I could find so far is to recreate the view, which is not practical as there are many DBs with many views

Is there any other way to update the host value of the user account without requiring recreating views.

thanks

Comment: I don't think so. The view doesn't remember the definer's permissions at the time it was created, it always uses the definer's current permissions.

Comment: The problem is that someuser@% and someuser@10.10.%.%, are two different users with different permissions. When you change the host part of the user, then someuser@% user no longer exists.

Comment: You can write a procedure that loops over all the views in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.routines` and redefines them with `SECURITY SECURITY INVOKER`

Comment: @Shadow They didn't change the host, they changed the grants assigned to the definer, and those grants no longer allow the view to work.

Comment: @Barmar this is not how I read the question.

Comment: Indeed, the question is confusing. What does "When host restriction is updated on the user account" mean? There are no host restrictions on user accounts. Usernames and hostnames are part of `GRANT` permissions.

Comment: Notice that the error message says `user@`, not `someuser@`. I assumed that's the username of the invoker, not the definer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like its documented limitation of MySql

Snippet from the [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/rename-user.html)

> RENAME USER causes the privileges held by the old user to be those
> held by the new user. However, RENAME USER does not automatically drop
> or invalidate databases or objects within them that the old user
> created. This includes stored programs or views for which the DEFINER
> attribute names the old user. Attempts to access such objects may
> produce an error if they execute in definer security context.

Full mysql official can be found [here](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=113969)